# A private class that can be passed anywhere as a parameter - is such a thing possible?

Tags: c#

I want to define a class, `ClassA`, that can be passed as a parameter to any method or class in a project (global scope). However, I want to enforce a constraint which will insure that `ClassA` can only be instantiated within the scope of a single `ClassB`. In other words, I want the class to have private scope with respect to `ClassA` while still being able to pass that object as a parameter to methods and classes distributed throughout the project.

Is this possible?

Comment: This would work better with semantic names.  (although I can't think of any offhand)

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass classes as parameters. You'll be happier in maintaining the code with using agreed interfaces, so you can modify your code in a more local way, as long as you have stable interfaces.

Comment: @jde: Yes.  That's essentially equivalent to my answer, except with an interface instead of a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `ClassA` abstract, and make a concrete implementation private to `ClassB` (as a nested class).

Comment: @Kirk: That won't prevent instantiation elsewhere.

Comment: This won't prevent other implementations of `ClassA` from being generated elsewhere - at least not without additional mechanisms in place.

Comment: I'd suggest to make constructors of `ClassA` internal to ensure that nobody will be able to subclass it except `ClassB`

Comment: @alpha: I would have said that, but it sounds like he's not writing a public library. @Reed: Correct.  You can't prevent other internal implementations.

Answer (score 4):

You can make ClassA a public abstract class, with an internal constructor.

ClassB can then define a class that derives from this, and creates the "real" instance.  This will prevent anybody outside of your assembly from generating types of ClassA.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding what you want to do here correctly.....

Make ClassB a nested class of ClassA and make the constructor for ClassA private.

Comment: That won't help.  The outer class can't call the private ctor.

Comment: I said ClassB is a subclass of ClassA, which is the one with the private constructor (not the other way around)

Comment: Oh, I see.  I like that idea.  However, you still can't prevent other classes from calling the inner class' ctor.